# What process do i need to highlight and then autosave - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

So I know what I want to do but not sure where to look or where to start.

I want to be able to select a row, have the row highlight and auto save a variable into a database.

Code below is what I want to accomplish, with out the OK button but it is just an example.

Thought I could use JavaScript and pass a variable to PHP but looks like I have to call an action to do that, anyway I can do what I want without clicking a button?

A little lost just really need pointed in the right direction.

> ```
> <table id="table">
>     <tr>
>         <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
>         <td>1 000€</td>
>         <td>1 200€</td>
>         <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
>         <td>1</td>
>         <td>F138</td>
>         <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
>         <td>1 000€</td>
>         <td>1 200€</td>
>         <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
>         <td>1</td>
>         <td>F138</td>
>         <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
>         <td>1 000€</td>
>         <td>1 200€</td>
>         <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
>         <td>1</td>
>         <td>F138</td>
>         <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
>
> <input type="button" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="fnselect()" />
>
>
> <script>
>     function highlight(e) {
>         if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
>         e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
>     }
>
>     var table = document.getElementById('table'),
>     selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
>     table.onclick = highlight;
>
>     function fnselect(){
>         var phpValue = $("tr.selected td:first" ).html();
>         alert (phpValue);
>     }
> </script>
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z22NU/1/

So I tried

Comment: the basic answer is  AJAX, and +1 for the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what @nogad said... ajax:

```
function fnselect(){
    var phpValue = $("tr.selected td:first" ).html();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'yourwebsite.com/your_php_file.php?phpValue='+phpValue);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Then in your php file you'll read that value like this: `$foo = $_GET['phpValue'];`